# LightGBM GPU version Memory Allocation Failure

Tags: python, gpu, lightgbm

I am using the GPU version of LightGBM and face the Memory Object Allocation Failure.I am using GPU A40 with 45GB memory so I am pretty sure that the memory of GPU is enough.So what's the problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im1uk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to provide more details for this question to be answerable. Please [don't post screenshots of logs or code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/3986677), and please attempt to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.